# ReactJS not render to div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to run my app, but have nothing in console and nothing in window, i was try to add `<script src="target/app.js"></script>` but it make error `Cannot GET /target/app.js`. Also i was in search how is work `create-react-app`, because it not use any scripts with bundle in html file but to no avail

This is `webpack.config.js`. But i don't think that it problem with webpack. Or it maybe problem with devServer?

```js
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/index.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
                include: /node_modules/,
                use: ['react-hot-loader/webpack'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                loader: 'prettier-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: require('./prettier.config')
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
                use: [{
                    /* inline if smaller than 10 KB, otherwise load as a file */
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 10000
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff2?|otf)$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', 'scss']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/target/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
        publicPath: '/public/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            R: 'ramda'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
        port: 3131
    }
}
```

This is `src/index.js`. In this place i don't see any errors and all should works fine.

```js
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
const App = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>Hello world!!</h1>
    </div>
)
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=”en”>
<head>
    <meta charset=”UTF-8">
    <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id=”root”></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like your dev server is mounted on `/public/`, did you try `/public/target/app.js`?

Comment: Could you please provide your `package.json` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be a webpack config issue, check if this fix works.

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/dist/'
},
```

Comment: No problem. This might help: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/start-using-quotation-marks-the-correct-way--webdesign-16905

Comment: Not working...  i change slanted quotes, but nothing new happens

Answer (score 0):

Try to add slash - `<script src="/target/app.js"></script>`